# XML Mapping: organize by sub-tags

Tags: xml, xslt, rss, feed

Hello all (please excuse my profanity in advance as I am not really skilled on those topics but trying to learn)

I'm stuck on something that should be simple:

I have an input of a basic file with pictures tags looking like this:

```
<PHOTO1>
 http://URL.COM/BCD
</PHOTO1>
<PHOTO2>
 http://URL.COM/CBC
</PHOTO2>
<PHOTO3>
http://URL.COM/ABC
</PHOTO3>
```

And a mapping to decode it that says :

```
<attachments>
  <xsl:for-each select="node()[starts-with(name(), 'PHOTO')]"><image><xsl:value-of select="." /></image></xsl:for-each>
</attachments>
```

The upload is done by alphabetical order, what I can't use, I would actually need it to display first Photo1 , than 2, etc.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: A [mcve] of your output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the output based on the tag-name as key can be achieved like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
  <attachments>
    <xsl:for-each select="node()[starts-with(name(), 'PHOTO')]">
      <xsl:sort select="name()" />                <!-- name() as key -->
      <image><xsl:value-of select="." /></image>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </attachments>
</xsl:template>
```